# Was "My People, My Country" financed by the state?

Tags: production, reference

"[My People, My Country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_People,_My_Country)" is a Chinese movie from 2019, created to commemorate the 70 years from the founding of the People’s Republic. It was the 14th highest grossing Non-English film of all time and featured immensely popular actors and renowned directors.

Given the commemoration, and that the film was praised by the state owned "People.cn", I assume that it was partly paid for by the Chinese state. But I can find no indication thereof. Does anyone have a source on this?

Prior to the Release of the film there was even a massive campaign of the same name as the film ([Chinese article](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%88%91%E5%92%8C%E6%88%91%E7%9A%84%E7%A5%96%E5%9B%BD/23230659)) but I cannot find concrete proof of a link between the two.

Comment: Apologies for the typo in the title. The film belongs to a trilogy. All other titles therein start with „my Country“.